# VMWare Workstation (11.1.0) - can PowerCLI be used to manage VMs?

Tags: windows, vmware, vmware-workstation, powercli

I have ESXi server on the server and VMWare Workstation 11.1.0 on Windows 7 laptop. To manage VMs on ESXi I use PowerCLI and to debug certain things I'd like to use the same code to manage VMs locally on the VMWare Workstation (clones of those on ESXi). Though whenever I try to connect using `Connect-VIServer -Server localhost` to local Workstation it requests username/password and then fails with the:

```
Connect-VIServer : 17/05/2015 13:00:43    Connect-VIServer        Could not determine user name and/or password for server localhost
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-VIServer localhost
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-VIServer], ViServerConnectionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ViCore_Login_CredentialNotFound,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.ConnectVIServer
```

Is it something I'm doing wrongly while connecting to the Workstation or Workstation doesn't support PowerCLI interface at all? Couldn't find any official statements on this matter of the vmware web-site or else where.

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2034803) Workstation can host a vSphere server. I'd expect PowerCLI to connect with that vSphere server, but I'd be surprised if Workstation itself listens for PowerCLI at all. If you find a definitive answer online or from VMware support, I'd be curious to hear it.

Comment: Interestingly enough VMWare Workstation doesn't plainly reject the request for connect, it asks for username/password and then reject the session as non-authenticated, so, theoretically it may support PowerCLI interface, though the question is how to make it working

Comment: [Not supported](https://communities.vmware.com/message/1526781) as of 2010, fwiw. Is there a hack to make it work? Beats me.

Answer (score 1):

Workstation does not support PowerCLI, so if you want test your powercli scripts you need a ESX.

But you can use [vmxtoolkit](https://github.com/bottkars/vmxtoolkit) to do cool stuff.

[Source](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/566121)